# How to call a non-void method from a void method?

Tags: java, function, methods

Is it possible to call an int method which receives an object and returns an int value from a void method by sending a temporary object to it?

When I tried this, I got nothing; the output window appears for a millisecond and vanishes. I used this code:

```
class test {

    int x (test ob) { return 10;}

    public static void main (String args[]) { new test().x(new test()) }

}
```

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Any sample example, where your output window appears and vanishes ?

Comment: You have multiple mistake in your code, first you haven't used the return value from method x and where are you printing the return value?

Comment: @user9836598 I have modified your code as per comment and added below as ans, have a look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If it just expects any object, you can pass `new Object()` and recieve the int value as a result.

Answer (score 0):

In a word yes. The return type of the calling method has no effect on the return type of the method being called. E.g.:

```
public class SomeClass() {
    public int increment(int i) {
        return i + 1;
    }

    public void printFiveTheHardWay() {
        System.out.println(increment(4));
    }
}
```

Comment: Output window appears for a millisecond and vanishes when I send an object to the int method (which receives an object) from the void method

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can call any method from Void method irrespective of return type of method , e.g:

Your example from comment should be like below:

```
class test {

    int x(test ob) {
        return 10;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(new test().x(new test()));
    }
}
```

More generic code for your better understanding here:

```
public class Foo {
    private Integer value;

    public Integer getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(Integer value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}

public class TestVoidMethodCall {

    public void voidMethod() {
        Foo f = new Foo();
        f.setValue(100);
        System.out.println(integerReturnMethod(f));
    }

    private Integer integerReturnMethod(Foo f) {
        return f.getValue();
    }
}
```

So, Calling method return type has no relation with called method return type.